# Mastercard Developer

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-5, mastercard

I need to integrate the Master Card API to my application to request payment and send the money to a bank account!

The app is created in Laravel, [developer.mastercard](https://developer.mastercard.com) has many apis, reading on the page I see that it has many apis and the one that seems to adapt to my needs is [moneysend](https://developer.mastercard.com/product/moneysend).

Add the dependency as the [document](https://developer.mastercard.com/documentation/moneysend/) says

> Composer requires mastercard/moneysend

But I'm confused how to continue!

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Install [composer](https://getcomposer.org/download/) if you already haven't and then on terminal (while in your app folder), just type `composer require mastercard/moneysend`

This will execute the [require](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#require) command and download/import the dependency in your Laravel application

Comment: Okay, this works fine, and then how do I use the api ?, to send the money to the bank account

Comment: I suggest posting a new question for this